# Could not find or load main class index.Indexer

Tags: java, maven

I have read many questions and i can't seem to be able to find an answer

This is Indexer and it is in package index:

```
package index;

public class Indexer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // let the magic happend
    }
}
```

and my pom contains:

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <!-- Build an executable JAR -->
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <!--<addClasspath>true</addClasspath>-->
                            <!--<classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>-->
                            <mainClass>index.Indexer</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

when i try to run it using java -jar jarname.jar i receive the follwing error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class index.Indexer
```

Comment: Are you sure that you're trying to run the right JAR? Run `mvn clean package`, then `java -jar target/jarname.jar`. Unzip the JAR and check the `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` file, is it correct?

Comment: can you provide your folder structure ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was i was not packaging it, only the manifest file was in the jar.
Now everything is okay